# SERVICIO DE NOTIFICACIONES SE DETIENE

Tags: java, android, servicio

Buenas, necesito ayuda porque llevo tiempo dandole vueltas a este asunto y no encuentro una solución para mi caso. Haber si me podéis echar una mano.

Mi aplicación es calendario del trabajo en el cual los usuarios podrán meter notas recordatorias en la fecha que deseen. He creado un sistema de notificaciones el cual consulta la base de datos para ver si hay una nota en ese día y lanza la notificación si la hay. He de decir que funciona bien a corto plazo pero a largo plazo el sistema cierra la aplicación y el servicio dejando muertas la notificaciones.

Necesito que el sistema no cierre el servicio que está activo ya que contiene datos que cuando se cierran se pierden.

Os dejo el código para que me deis ideas tanto de como optimizar el código como de como puedo solucionar el problema. He de volver a decir que el código funciona pero a corto plazo.

-CODIGO DONDE SE ARRANCA EL SERVICIO EN LA ACTIVITY PRINCIPAL.

```
private void ActivarServicioNotificaciones(){


        EquipoMeses = EquipoLayout;
        EquipoJuntoMeses = EquipoJuntoLayout;
        mesMeses = MesLayout;
        ServicioActivadoMeses = 1;


    Intent intent = new Intent(Meses.this, Notificaciones.class);
    if (ServicioActivadoLayout == 0){
        ToastPersonalizado miToast = new ToastPersonalizado(this, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        miToast.show("Activado el servicio de notificaciones del "+ EquipoMeses);

    }

    intent.putExtra("mes",mesMeses);
    intent.putExtra("mesLetra", MesLetra);
    intent.putExtra("dia", DiaLayout);
    intent.putExtra("dianulo", dianuloMeses);
    intent.putExtra("diaSemana", diaSemanaMeses);
    intent.putExtra("Equipo", EquipoMeses);
    intent.putExtra("EquipoJunto", EquipoJuntoMeses);
    intent.putExtra("ServicioActivado", ServicioActivadoMeses);
    intent.putExtra("PrimeraNotificacion", PrimeraNotificacionLayout);
    intent.putExtra("AlarmaConectadaOnOff", AlarmaConectadaOnOffLayout);
    intent.putExtra("notificacionlanzada", notificacionlanzada);

    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getService(Meses.this, 0, intent, 0);

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 59, sender);
    startService(intent);

}
```

-CLASE DONDE SE GESTIONA EL SERVICIO.

```
public class Notificaciones extends Service {
public static final String TAG = "Servicio";

private boolean isRunning = false;

private int DiaSer;
private int MesSer;
private int MesSer1;
private String MesSerLetra;
private int hora;
private int minuto;


private String mesnotificacionletra;
private String equiponotificacion;
private String Activ = null;

public String mesLetraServicio;
public int mesServicio;
public int diaServicio;
public int dianuloServicio;
public int diaSemanaServicio;
public String EquipoServicio;
public String EquipoJuntoServicio;
public int ServicioActivadoServicio;
public int NotificacionLanzadaServicio;
private String mesletraServicio;
private Integer mesnotificacion;
private int ContaNotificaciones;
private int PrimeraNotificacionServicio;
private int AlarmaConectadaServicio;

public Notas[] datosLista;
public SQLiteDatabase db;
public ControlNotas usdbh;

public int HayDatos = 0;

private int HoraNotificacion;
private int MinutoNotificacion;

public static final String KEY_TEST = null;

private int ContadorNotificacion = 0;


@Override
public void onCreate() {

    isRunning = true;

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, final int startId) {



    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    DiaSer = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    MesSer = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    MesSer1 = MesSer + 1;
    hora = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    minuto = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    mesnotificacion = MesSer1;
    ComprobarMesPequeño();


    mesServicio = intent.getIntExtra("mes", 0);
    mesLetraServicio = intent.getStringExtra("mesLetra");
    diaServicio = intent.getIntExtra("dia", 0);
    dianuloServicio = intent.getIntExtra("dianulo", 0);
    diaSemanaServicio = intent.getIntExtra("diaSemana", 0);
    EquipoServicio = intent.getStringExtra("Equipo");
    EquipoJuntoServicio = intent.getStringExtra("EquipoJunto");
    ServicioActivadoServicio = intent.getIntExtra("ServicioActivado", 0);
    PrimeraNotificacionServicio = intent.getIntExtra("PrimeraNotificacion", 0);
    AlarmaConectadaServicio = intent.getIntExtra("AlarmaConectadaOnOff", 0);
    NotificacionLanzadaServicio = intent.getIntExtra("notificacionlanzada", 0);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            //Abrimos la base de datos 'DBControlNotificacion' en modo escritura
            ControlNotificacion cont = new ControlNotificacion(getApplicationContext(), "DBControlNotificacion.sqlite", null, 1);
            SQLiteDatabase db = cont.getReadableDatabase();

            String cod = "1";
            Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT equipo, horanotificacion, minutonotificacion FROM ControlNotificacion where codigo=" + cod, null);


            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                String equ = c.getString(0);
                int hora = c.getInt(1);
                int minuto = c.getInt(2);

                equiponotificacion = equ;
                HoraNotificacion = hora;
                MinutoNotificacion = minuto;


                db.close();
                c.close();

            }

            int MinutoMasUno = MinutoNotificacion + 1;
            if (hora == HoraNotificacion && minuto == MinutoMasUno){
                NotificacionLanzadaServicio = 0;
                ContadorNotificacion = 0;
            }

            if (hora == HoraNotificacion && minuto == MinutoNotificacion && NotificacionLanzadaServicio == 0) {

                if (ContadorNotificacion == 0){
                    //Abrimos la base de datos 'DBUsuarios' en modo escritura
                    usdbh = new ControlNotas(Notificaciones.this, "DBnotas" + equiponotificacion + ".sqlite", null, 1);

                    db = usdbh.getReadableDatabase();

                    Cursor ConsultaNotas = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM 'notas' " +
                            "WHERE diames='" + DiaSer + "'" +
                            "AND mesmes='" + mesnotificacionletra + "'", null);

                    if (ConsultaNotas.moveToFirst()) {
                        //Recorremos el cursor hasta que no haya más registros
                        datosLista = new Notas[ConsultaNotas.getCount()];
                        int i = 0;
                        do {
                            datosLista[i] = new Notas();
                            datosLista[i].setDiames(ConsultaNotas.getInt(0));
                            datosLista[i].setMesmes(ConsultaNotas.getString(1));
                            datosLista[i].setNota(ConsultaNotas.getString(2));
                            i++;
                        } while (ConsultaNotas.moveToNext());

                        db.close();

                        if (isRunning) {
                            // Preparamos el intent que será lanzado si la notificación es seleccionada
                            Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

                            NotificacionLanzadaServicio =1;
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Notificaciones.this, Meses.class);
                            intent.putExtra("mes", mesnotificacion);
                            intent.putExtra("mesLetra", mesnotificacionletra);
                            intent.putExtra("dia", DiaSer);
                            intent.putExtra("dianulo", dianuloServicio);
                            intent.putExtra("diaSemana", diaSemanaServicio);
                            intent.putExtra("Equipo", EquipoServicio);
                            intent.putExtra("EquipoJunto", EquipoJuntoServicio);
                            intent.putExtra("ServicioActivado", ServicioActivadoServicio);
                            intent.putExtra("PrimeraNotificacion", PrimeraNotificacionServicio);
                            intent.putExtra("AlarmaConectadaOnOff", AlarmaConectadaServicio);
                            intent.putExtra("notificacionlanzada", NotificacionLanzadaServicio);

                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                            PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(Notificaciones.this, 0, intent, 0);

                            // Creamos la notificación.
                            CharSequence ticker = "Aviso de Nota";
                            CharSequence contentTitle = "Calendario Verallia Sevilla";
                            CharSequence contentText = "Tienes una nueva nota para hoy";
                            Notification noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(Notificaciones.this)
                                    .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                                    .setTicker(ticker)
                                    .setContentTitle(contentTitle)
                                    .setContentText(contentText)
                                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icono_aplicacion_2018_notificacion)
                                    .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000})
                                    .setSound(soundUri)
                                    .build();
                            NotificationManager notificationManager =
                                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                            // Ocultamos la notificación si ha sido ya seleccionada
                            noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                            notificationManager.notify(0, noti);

                            ContadorNotificacion = 1;
                        }


                    }
                }

            }



        }
    }).start();

    return Service.START_STICKY;
}


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    isRunning = false;
    stopSelf();

}

private void ComprobarMesPequeño(){
    switch (mesnotificacion){
        case 1:
            mesnotificacionletra = "Enero";
            break;
        case 2:
            mesnotificacionletra = "Febrero";
            break;
        case 3:
            mesnotificacionletra = "Marzo";
            break;
        case 4:
            mesnotificacionletra = "Abril";
            break;
        case 5:
            mesnotificacionletra = "Mayo";
            break;
        case 6:
            mesnotificacionletra = "Junio";
            break;
        case 7:
            mesnotificacionletra = "Julio";
            break;
        case 8:
            mesnotificacionletra = "Agosto";
            break;
        case 9:
            mesnotificacionletra = "Septiembre";
            break;
        case 10:
            mesnotificacionletra = "Octubre";
            break;
        case 11:
            mesnotificacionletra = "Noviembre";
            break;
        case 12:
            mesnotificacionletra = "Diciembre";
            break;
    }
}
```

}

ESTO ES LO QUE ME SALE EN EL LOGCAT.

```
01-11 22:57:39.668 5862-5862/com.navasfj.calendario18 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.navasfj.calendario18, PID: 5862
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.navasfj.calendario18.Notificaciones@af490ce with null: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.content.Intent.getIntExtra(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3383)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap21(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1612)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6229)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:891)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:781)
         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.content.Intent.getIntExtra(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
            at com.navasfj.calendario18.Notificaciones.onStartCommand(Notificaciones.java:91)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3366)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap21(ActivityThread.java) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1612) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6229) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:891) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:781)
```

por favor si no queda claro lo que quiero hacer decídmelo e intentaré aclararlo mejor.

Gracias por adelantado por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: "Se detiene" puede deberse a miles de causas, que se muestra en el LogCat?

Comment: En el movil me muestra el típico mensaje de... la aplicación "Calendario" se ha detenido y hasta ahí llego el servicio de notificaciones. No se como ver el LogCat, porque probando en casa no me da ese error es cuanto pasa cierto tiempo (horas).

Comment: Revisa https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html?hl=es  , si deseas desarrollar en android y evitar perder días en lugar de segundos al buscar un problema, debes aprender a usar el LogCat.

Comment: Me acaba de saltar el error en modo de depuración y he podido copiar el LogCat, lo he pegado en la pregunta original por si sirve de algo.

Comment: ok después de : public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, final int startId) { agrega: super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId); y comenta que resultado tienes

Comment: acabo de añadir el código que me has dado, voy a esperar el resultado. Lo que si te comento es que después de darme ese error le he metido unas lineas de depuración para que me mostrase en el LogCat lo que estaba pasando y me he dado cuenta de que cuando daba ese fallo era porque los datos que mandaban eran 0 con lo cual daba fallo al leer los datos de la base de datos, pero que al cerrar la aplicación del móvil al poco tiempo se volvía a poner en marcha el servicio manteniendo de nuevo los datos originales. De todas formas quedo a la espera de resultados con la linea nueva de código.

Comment: ha vuelto a fallar con la linea de código que me has dado

Answer (score -1):

Estas teniendo un NullPointerException en la siguiente linea:

```
  mesServicio = intent.getIntExtra("mes", 0);
```

Eso es porque el parametro Intent del metodo onStartCommand puede venir con valor nulo. Podes ver la documentacion del mismo [aqui](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int)).

Comment: Lo entiendo pero no sé cómo ponerle remedio a eso

Comment: @user3737118 fijate que un motivo por el cual puede venir en null, es porque no estas retornando START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY.  cambia la linea   return Service.START_STICKY por return START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY